# Label encoding of date and create new attribute based on quarter using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a date and want to create a new attributes based on the date. For example.

```
 date                    quarter1    quarter2    quarter3   quarter4
2/3/2020(mm/dd/yyyy)        1            0.           0.        0
11/11/2020                  0            0            0         1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast the date column and use `quarter` function, then apply an when + otherwise condition to create the columns:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

qtrs = ['quarter1','quarter2','quarter3','quarter4']
df = df.select("*",F.concat(F.lit("quarter"),
                      F.quarter(F.to_date("date",'M/d/yyyy'))).alias("quarters"))\
.select("*",*[F.when(F.col("quarters")==col,1).otherwise(0).alias(col) for col in qtrs])\
.drop("quarters")
```

---

```
df.show()
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      date|quarter1|quarter2|quarter3|quarter4|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  2/3/2020|       1|       0|       0|       0|
|11/11/2020|       0|       0|       0|       1|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Per OP's request, adding approach with `withColumn`:

```
df = (df.withColumn("quarters",F.concat(F.lit("quarter"),
                      F.quarter(F.to_date("date",'M/d/yyyy'))))
   .withColumn("quarter1",F.when(F.col("quarters")=='quarter1',1).otherwise(0))
   .withColumn("quarter2",F.when(F.col("quarters")=='quarter2',1).otherwise(0))
   .withColumn("quarter3",F.when(F.col("quarters")=='quarter3',1).otherwise(0))
   .withColumn("quarter4",F.when(F.col("quarters")=='quarter4',1).otherwise(0))
   .drop("quarters")
)

df.show()
```

Comment: How to implement using df.withColumn and delete the quarters column !?

Comment: I am trying to append this existing dataframe df !?

Comment: @Thedatageek 1: For dropping the "quarters" column just add `.drop('quarters')` at the end of the code. 2: Using select with a loop is better here than writing 4 `.withColumn` lines. 3: Spark dataframes are immutable , meaning you can only create a copy with additional columns and cannot modify an existing dataframe , if you want to assign this to the existing variable, `df=....` instead of `out=...` in the code

Comment: How to add out to existing df??

Comment: I have already have a dataframe df with other columns,how to add this out to that df?

Comment: @Thedatageek it does exactly that, there was a typo in my assignment, try now?

Comment: Can you please edit with withcolumn instead of select, getting some error when i try to read the final df !

Comment: @Thedatageek Added , also I am not getting any error, so you might check the data once

Comment: @Thedatageek Did it not solve your problem? Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)